# Mongoose populate not working?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mean i want to reference a collection to another collection using populate method, but unable to do so

Company schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ClientEmployee  = require('../models/clientEmployee')

var CompanySchema = new Schema({
companyId : {type: String, required  :true, unique : true},
companyName : {type: String, lowercase : true, required  :true, unique : 
true},
phone : {type: String},
mobile :  {type: String},
website : {type: String, lowercase : true, required  :true, unique : true},
address : {type: String},
city : {type: String},
zipcode : {type: String},
country : {type: String},
vatNumber : {type: String},
primaryContacts : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ClientEmployee'}]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company',CompanySchema)
```

I am trying to populate clientemployee to company

ClientEmployee schema

```
var ClientContactSchema = new Schema({
     var mongoose = require('mongoose');
     var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
     var ClientEmployeeSchema = new Schema({
     username : {type: String, required  :true, unique : true},
     contactName : {type: String, required  :true, unique : true},
     status : {type: String},
     email :  {type: String, lowercase : true, required  :true, unique : 
      true},
     phone : {type: Number, required  :true, unique : true},
     mobile : {type: Number, required  :true, unique : true},
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('ClientEmployee', ClientEmployeeSchema)
```

Angular routes

Update company route

```
$scope.updateCompanies = function () {

$http.put('/api/companies',$scope.selectedComapny)
    .success(function(data) {

    });
};
```

Add clientemployee route

```
$scope.addClientEmployee = function () { 
$http.post('/api/clientEmployees', $scope.clientEmployee)
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.updateCompanies();
    });
 }
```

Express Routes

Updating company route

```
router.put('/companies', function(req, res){
Company
.findOne({companyName : req.body.companyName})
.populate('primaryContacts')
.exec()
});
```

Client employee Route

```
router.post('/clientEmployees', function(req, res) {
var clientEmployee = new ClientEmployee();
clientEmployee.username = req.body.username;
clientEmployee.contactName = req.body.contactName;
clientEmployee.status = req.body.status;
clientEmployee.email = req.body.email;
clientEmployee.phone = req.body.phone;
clientEmployee.mobile = req.body.mobile;

clientEmployee.save();

res.send('Employee created')
});`
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: Its give me undefined variable which is present in populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must create an ClientEmployee

```
newClientEmployee = new ClientEmployee({username: "Tetest", contact: "", ...});
newClientEmployee.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return;

    // Then you can attach him to the Company
    newCompany = new Company({companyId: "", companyName: "Corporate", ...});
    newCompany.primaryContacts.push(newClientEmployee._id);
    newCompany.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return;
    });
});
```

Then, to get your Company with primaryContacts:

```
Company
.findOne({companyName : req.body.companyName})
.populate('primaryContacts')
.exec(function(err, company) {
    if (err) return;
    console.log(company); // Print your companies with your PrimaryContacts array
    console.log(company.primaryContacts[0]); // Will display "Tetest" if req.body.companyName = Corporate
})
```

Comment: Hey dude my company is already present in Database so why i create new company there..??

Comment: It's the same:
Company.findOne({companyName : req.body.companyName}).populate('primaryContacts').exec(function(company, err) {
    company.primaryContacts.push(YourClientEmployee._id);
})

Comment: How i take clientEmployee id ?? any idea

Comment: When you save it, you will have an _id attribute created by MongoDB